Between estimator versus pooled OLS/Random effects
I am familiar that, for example, Hausman's test can help me pick which is better between a fixed-effects and a random-effects model. But is there a test that can help me choose between a between estimator model (implemented in R using plm (y~x, model="between")) versus a pooled OLS (plm(y~x, model="pooling") and a random effects model (plm(y~x, model="random")?
Thank you!
